# How to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to draw non-standard shapes?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image which is a bubble shape, and I wish to add text to the middle of the image, so I tried to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to redraw the image.

The code is as following:

```
 let imageSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)

        // the rect in which the image will be drawn in
        let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageSize)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, true, 1.0)
        // begining drawing things

        // first, we draw the image in the specified rect
        image.draw(in: imageRect)

        let attributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
                           NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]
        let text = "55"
        let size = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 20 - size.width / 2, y: 20 - size.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
```

but I get a square with a black background with the desired image inside: 
[image]

the blue is the original image, the black is the re-drawn image. Anyone knows how can I draw the image as the original image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `false`, not `true`, to the 2nd argument (the `opaque` parameter) of the call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 1.0)
```

You should also pass `0` as the 3rd argument (`scale`) so the image is scaled to match the current device's screen scale.

Comment: Is there a problem with this answer or is some child revenge down voting?